# Fail to serialize JSON Objective-c

Tags: objective-c, json, nsdictionary, nsjsonserialization

I have a problem. When I try to make test my json, it says that it is not valid. But when I test it with online services, it reads it well.

The code I use to test if json is valid is:

```
NSString* stringRes = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
[NSJSONSerialization isValidJSONObject:stringRes];
```

Where stringRes is son string in NSString format.(From data response)
JSON :

```
{
"response": [
9,
{
  "id": 47,
  "from_id": 211551056,
  "to_id": -101815039,
  "date": 1442585775,
  "post_type": "post",
  "text": "Кто на андроид кодит хоть немножк ? Хотя бы hello world ?",
  "can_edit": 1,
  "created_by": 211551056,
  "can_delete": 1,
  "post_source": {
    "type": "api",
    "platform": "iphone"
  },
  "comments": {
    "count": 0,
    "can_post": 1
  },
  "likes": {
    "count": 0,
    "user_likes": 0,
    "can_like": 1,
    "can_publish": 0
  },
  "reposts": {
    "count": 0,
    "user_reposted": 0
  },
  "online": 1,
  "reply_count": 0
},
{
  "id": 43,
  "from_id": 217702824,
  "to_id": -101815039,
  "date": 1442555658,
  "post_type": "post",
  "text": "Учебник по географии",
  "can_delete": 1,
  "attachment": {
    "type": "doc",
    "doc": {
      "did": 419802605,
      "owner_id": 217702824,
      "title": "11_geo_m_2012.pdf",
      "size": 92318316,
      "ext": "pdf",
      "url": "http://vk.com/doc217702824_419802605?hash=5eb9bb9753a6f88e88&dl=fcadca27db5845a002&api=1",
      "access_key": "8e4218746055687cc2"
    }
  },
  "attachments": [
    {
      "type": "doc",
      "doc": {
        "did": 419802605,
        "owner_id": 217702824,
        "title": "11_geo_m_2012.pdf",
        "size": 92318316,
        "ext": "pdf",
        "url": "http://vk.com/doc217702824_419802605?hash=5eb9bb9753a6f88e88&dl=fcadca27db5845a002&api=1",
        "access_key": "8e4218746055687cc2"
      }
    }
  ],
  "post_source": {
    "type": "api",
    "platform": "android"
  },
  "comments": {
    "count": 0,
    "can_post": 1
  },
  "likes": {
    "count": 3,
    "user_likes": 0,
    "can_like": 1,
    "can_publish": 0
  },
  "reposts": {
    "count": 0,
    "user_reposted": 0
  },
  "online": 0,
  "reply_count": 0
},
{
  "id": 37,
  "from_id": 211551056,
  "to_id": -101815039,
  "date": 1442502437,
  "post_type": "post",
  "text": "У кого айфон, + в комменты",
  "can_delete": 1,
  "attachment": {
    "type": "poll",
    "poll": {
      "poll_id": 195892301,
      "question": "Удобно смотреть расписание ?(На сайте)"
    }
  },
  "attachments": [
    {
      "type": "poll",
      "poll": {
        "poll_id": 195892301,
        "question": "Удобно смотреть расписание ?(На сайте)"
      }
    }
  ],
  "post_source": {
    "type": "api",
    "platform": "iphone"
  },
  "comments": {
    "count": 5,
    "can_post": 1
  },
  "likes": {
    "count": 0,
    "user_likes": 0,
    "can_like": 1,
    "can_publish": 0
  },
  "reposts": {
    "count": 0,
    "user_reposted": 0
  },
  "online": 1,
  "reply_count": 5
},
{
  "id": 36,
  "from_id": 249011483,
  "to_id": -101815039,
  "date": 1442500757,
  "post_type": "post",
  "text": "Домашку выложить не забудьте ",
  "can_delete": 1,
  "post_source": {
    "type": "api",
    "platform": "iphone"
  },
  "comments": {
    "count": 0,
    "can_post": 1
  },
  "likes": {
    "count": 1,
    "user_likes": 0,
    "can_like": 1,
    "can_publish": 0
  },
  "reposts": {
    "count": 0,
    "user_reposted": 0
  },
  "online": 1,
  "reply_count": 0
},
{
  "id": 28,
  "from_id": 211551056,
  "to_id": -101815039,
  "date": 1442306249,
  "post_type": "post",
  "text": "",
  "can_delete": 1,
  "media": {
    "type": "photo",
    "owner_id": -101815039,
    "item_id": 381477357,
    "thumb_src": "http://cs624425.vk.me/v624425056/49e35/_w_YDirrrQU.jpg"
  },
  "attachment": {
    "type": "photo",
    "photo": {
      "pid": 381477357,
      "aid": -8,
      "owner_id": -101815039,
      "user_id": 211551056,
      "src": "http://cs624425.vk.me/v624425056/49e35/_w_YDirrrQU.jpg",
      "src_big": "http://cs624425.vk.me/v624425056/49e36/439edT8aXks.jpg",
      "src_small": "http://cs624425.vk.me/v624425056/49e34/uLxZj9yF1F4.jpg",
      "src_xbig": "http://cs624425.vk.me/v624425056/49e37/nhvaG43cV-Y.jpg",
      "src_xxbig": "http://cs624425.vk.me/v624425056/49e38/Ox54xM039hg.jpg",
      "width": 960,
      "height": 720,
      "text": "",
      "created": 1442306250,
      "lat": 55.785025,
      "long": 37.706605,
      "post_id": 28,
      "access_key": "454823aa95a2ee9fbc"
    }
  },
  "attachments": [
    {
      "type": "photo",
      "photo": {
        "pid": 381477357,
        "aid": -8,
        "owner_id": -101815039,
        "user_id": 211551056,
        "src": "http://cs624425.vk.me/v624425056/49e35/_w_YDirrrQU.jpg",
        "src_big": "http://cs624425.vk.me/v624425056/49e36/439edT8aXks.jpg",
        "src_small": "http://cs624425.vk.me/v624425056/49e34/uLxZj9yF1F4.jpg",
        "src_xbig": "http://cs624425.vk.me/v624425056/49e37/nhvaG43cV-Y.jpg",
        "src_xxbig": "http://cs624425.vk.me/v624425056/49e38/Ox54xM039hg.jpg",
        "width": 960,
        "height": 720,
        "text": "",
        "created": 1442306250,
        "lat": 55.785025,
        "long": 37.706605,
        "post_id": 28,
        "access_key": "454823aa95a2ee9fbc"
      }
    }
  ],
  "post_source": {
    "type": "api",
    "platform": "iphone"
  },
  "comments": {
    "count": 0,
    "can_post": 1
  },
  "likes": {
    "count": 1,
    "user_likes": 0,
    "can_like": 1,
    "can_publish": 0
  },
  "reposts": {
    "count": 0,
    "user_reposted": 0
  },
  "online": 1,
  "reply_count": 0
},
{
  "id": 27,
  "from_id": 211551056,
  "to_id": -101815039,
  "date": 1442306164,
  "post_type": "post",
  "text": "",
  "can_delete": 1,
  "media": {
    "type": "photo",
    "owner_id": -101815039,
    "item_id": 381477244,
    "thumb_src": "http://cs624425.vk.me/v624425056/49e2c/kttj5pUpjTk.jpg"
  },
  "attachment": {
    "type": "photo",
    "photo": {
      "pid": 381477244,
      "aid": -8,
      "owner_id": -101815039,
      "user_id": 211551056,
      "src": "http://cs624425.vk.me/v624425056/49e2c/kttj5pUpjTk.jpg",
      "src_big": "http://cs624425.vk.me/v624425056/49e2d/ihg9szTvLew.jpg",
      "src_small": "http://cs624425.vk.me/v624425056/49e2b/GpS0xwCa66c.jpg",
      "src_xbig": "http://cs624425.vk.me/v624425056/49e2e/pe4tflJokqs.jpg",
      "src_xxbig": "http://cs624425.vk.me/v624425056/49e2f/7vkU8nUyNxc.jpg",
      "width": 960,
      "height": 720,
      "text": "",
      "created": 1442306166,
      "lat": 55.785083,
      "long": 37.711116,
      "post_id": 27,
      "access_key": "cb01ac011f4abbc0af"
    }
  },
  "attachments": [
    {
      "type": "photo",
      "photo": {
        "pid": 381477244,
        "aid": -8,
        "owner_id": -101815039,
        "user_id": 211551056,
        "src": "http://cs624425.vk.me/v624425056/49e2c/kttj5pUpjTk.jpg",
        "src_big": "http://cs624425.vk.me/v624425056/49e2d/ihg9szTvLew.jpg",
        "src_small": "http://cs624425.vk.me/v624425056/49e2b/GpS0xwCa66c.jpg",
        "src_xbig": "http://cs624425.vk.me/v624425056/49e2e/pe4tflJokqs.jpg",
        "src_xxbig": "http://cs624425.vk.me/v624425056/49e2f/7vkU8nUyNxc.jpg",
        "width": 960,
        "height": 720,
        "text": "",
        "created": 1442306166,
        "lat": 55.785083,
        "long": 37.711116,
        "post_id": 27,
        "access_key": "cb01ac011f4abbc0af"
      }
    }
  ],
  "post_source": {
    "type": "api",
    "platform": "iphone"
  },
  "comments": {
    "count": 0,
    "can_post": 1
  },
  "likes": {
    "count": 1,
    "user_likes": 0,
    "can_like": 1,
    "can_publish": 0
  },
  "reposts": {
    "count": 0,
    "user_reposted": 0
  },
  "online": 1,
  "reply_count": 0
},
{
  "id": 16,
  "from_id": 249011483,
  "to_id": -101815039,
  "date": 1442069345,
  "post_type": "post",
  "text": "Кто нибудь сделал алгебру ?",
  "can_delete": 1,
  "post_source": {
    "type": "api",
    "platform": "iphone"
  },
  "comments": {
    "count": 6,
    "can_post": 1
  },
  "likes": {
    "count": 3,
    "user_likes": 0,
    "can_like": 1,
    "can_publish": 0
  },
  "reposts": {
    "count": 0,
    "user_reposted": 0
  },
  "online": 1,
  "reply_count": 6
},
{
  "id": 9,
  "from_id": 127082413,
  "to_id": -101815039,
  "date": 1441911418,
  "post_type": "post",
  "text": "Официальная информациия ,староста нашей группы Александр Кондор!",
  "can_delete": 1,
  "post_source": {
    "type": "api",
    "platform": "android"
  },
  "comments": {
    "count": 6,
    "can_post": 1
  },
  "likes": {
    "count": 2,
    "user_likes": 0,
    "can_like": 1,
    "can_publish": 0
  },
  "reposts": {
    "count": 0,
    "user_reposted": 0
  },
  "online": 1,
  "reply_count": 6
},
{
  "id": 1,
  "from_id": -101815039,
  "to_id": -101815039,
  "date": 1441656588,
  "post_type": "post",
  "text": "",
  "can_delete": 1,
  "can_pin": 1,
  "media": {
    "type": "photo",
    "owner_id": -101815039,
    "item_id": 380592775,
    "thumb_src": "http://cs629111.vk.me/v629111548/e99f/DcV1yHZK1fw.jpg"
  },
  "attachment": {
    "type": "photo",
    "photo": {
      "pid": 380592775,
      "aid": -6,
      "owner_id": -101815039,
      "user_id": 100,
      "src": "http://cs629111.vk.me/v629111548/e99f/DcV1yHZK1fw.jpg",
      "src_big": "http://cs629111.vk.me/v629111548/e9a0/Qf8q8PpH7Jg.jpg",
      "src_small": "http://cs629111.vk.me/v629111548/e99e/2Jq8e-0SptQ.jpg",
      "src_xbig": "http://cs629111.vk.me/v629111548/e9a1/Uha0MvOoVCU.jpg",
      "src_xxbig": "http://cs629111.vk.me/v629111548/e9a2/v8hqUldA6Kk.jpg",
      "width": 730,
      "height": 1024,
      "text": "",
      "created": 1441656588,
      "post_id": 1
    }
  },
  "attachments": [
    {
      "type": "photo",
      "photo": {
        "pid": 380592775,
        "aid": -6,
        "owner_id": -101815039,
        "user_id": 100,
        "src": "http://cs629111.vk.me/v629111548/e99f/DcV1yHZK1fw.jpg",
        "src_big": "http://cs629111.vk.me/v629111548/e9a0/Qf8q8PpH7Jg.jpg",
        "src_small": "http://cs629111.vk.me/v629111548/e99e/2Jq8e-0SptQ.jpg",
        "src_xbig": "http://cs629111.vk.me/v629111548/e9a1/Uha0MvOoVCU.jpg",
        "src_xxbig": "http://cs629111.vk.me/v629111548/e9a2/v8hqUldA6Kk.jpg",
        "width": 730,
        "height": 1024,
        "text": "",
        "created": 1441656588,
        "post_id": 1
      }
    }
  ],
  "post_source": {
    "type": "api",
    "platform": "android",
    "data": "profile_photo"
  },
  "comments": {
    "count": 0,
    "can_post": 1
  },
  "likes": {
    "count": 0,
    "user_likes": 0,
    "can_like": 1,
    "can_publish": 0
  },
  "reposts": {
    "count": 0,
    "user_reposted": 0
  },
  "online": 1,
  "reply_count": 0
 }
]
}
```

UPD: Solved by using

```
NSData* data = [stringRes dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

isValidJSONObject tests if a JSON object (a NSDictionary or NSArray) can be successfully converted to JSON data.

It is not for testing if an NSData object contains valid JSON data. To test for valid JSON data you just call

[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data ...]

and check if the return value is nil or not.

Comment: Heh... I used that before and it broke my app... Then I thought to test it.

Comment: NSArray* dict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:stringRes options:NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves error:&error];